# How to implement Haskell instance in python?

Tags: python, haskell, inheritance, multiple-inheritance

In Haskell if you create an instance like this:

```
instance (Eq a) => POrd (Set a) where
    ...
```

Then if you need to do the same thing in python, does it mean that we are creating a class called Set, which inherits from another class called POrd, and Set inherits from a class called Eq? Something like:

```
class Eq:
    ...

class POrd:
    ...

class Set(Eq, POrd): 
    ...
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Python code makes no assumption on the relationship between `Eq` and `POrd`, but `Set` does inherit from both these classes. Each of them can be completely unrelated.

To have that "chain", where `Eq` inherits from `POrd` and `Set` from `Eq`, would translate into something like:

```
class POrd:
    ...

class Eq(POrd):
    ...

class Set(Eq): 
    ...
```